# Convert vector of strings into a vector of objects-names

Tags: r, string, object, type-conversion

Example Data:

```
a <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse")
b <- c("spoon", "fork", "knife")
c <- c("auto", "boot", "bike")
```

Generate Variables:

```
objects <-c(a,b,c)
strings <-c("a","b","c")
```

Give me the length of all strings:

```
> nchar(objects)
[1] 3 3 5 5 4 5 4 4 4

> nchar(strings)
[1] 1 1 1
```

## What do i have to do to "strings" to give me the same result as "objects"?

The closest i have gotten so far:

```
> nchar(eval(parse(text=strings)))
[1] 4 4 4
>
```

But where is the rest?

Comment: I believe you want: `nchar(unlist(lapply(strings,function(s) eval(parse(text=s)))))`

Comment: Thank you. I will test your answers in my function and check the correct one if i get the result i want.

Comment: In case, you need a `for` loop, here is one `v1 <- vector();
 for(j in strings){
 v1 <- c(v1, nchar(get(j)))
 }`
> v1

Comment: @aichao. if you reply to my post i can set your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to loop over each element of `strings` and apply `eval(parse(text=s))`. Then `unlist` to a vector and call `nchar`:

```
nchar(unlist(lapply(strings,function(s) eval(parse(text=s)))))
##[1] 3 3 5 5 4 5 4 4 4
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the objects in a `list`, `unlist` it to a `vector` and get the `nchar`

```
nchar(unlist(mget(strings), use.names=FALSE))
#[1] 3 3 5 5 4 5 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `sapply` over each element of `strings`, `get` the value of element and calculate the number of characters with `nchar`

```
c(sapply(strings, function(x) nchar(get(x))))
#[1] 3 3 5 5 4 5 4 4 4
```